# Python: Difference in output of vim and cat

Tags: python, vim

Upon working with files I found a difference in the output of `vim` and `cat`. While on vim we see the ctrl characters such as ^M, ^H; cat over the same file interprets this output and convert them to carriage, backspace etc. When I read the file through python these control characters gets converted to their python representation i.e. '\r' or '\x08' for backspace.

Here is the problem. I am reading this file line by line via Python which contains many control characters. Is there a way that python interprets these control characters the way `cat` does it. So when it encounters an '\x08' I want it to delete the character.

I can write a python program to analyze the string and take actions based on control characters but there are many different types of them. I want to know if a utility exists in python which can do this. An example would be:

This is how the string is stored. (can be seen on writing to a file but not on printing to the terminal)

```
x = "Hell   \x08\x08\0x8o"
```

This is how I want it to be stored (if we print the above string we get this but this isn't how it is stored.)

```
"Hello?"
```

One point that I is necessary to reiterate is that when we print the output, it looks just fine but if I write it to a file or convert it to a list then I see the control characters

```
lst = []
for i in x:
   lst.insert(-1,i)
print x
['H', 'e', ' l', 'l', ' ', ' ', ' ', '\x08', '\x08', '\x08', 'o']
```

and this is my expected output

```
['H', 'e', 'l ', 'l', 'o']
```

Any effort to print the string is interpreted by terminal but that's not how the string is stored. If we write the string to a file then also we can see the difference.

Comment: Please give sample input and an MVCE which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You basically need to simulate a terminal emulator: scan the string from left to right, and when you encounter a `\x08`, remove it *and* the previous character. If you see a `\r`, remove it and everything between it and the previous `\n`.

Comment: @chepner: I have considered the option of emulating the string but I am wondering if something exists already which does this.

Comment: Unlikely, because this isn't a question about data. For example, my suggestions for `\x08` and `\r` only hold if you are simulating a terminal that completely overwrites previous characters. A terminal is allowed to display `-\x08|` as something that looks like a plus sign, for instance, something that doesn't even *have* a Unicode character. You could replace it with `+`, though, as an approximation.

Comment: To make your question even harder: `'\033[1;1H'` moves the cursor to position (1, 1) of the terminal. Maybe you have to decide what kind of control sequences you want to handle?

Comment: @Cychih: Any control sequence which can modify the string needs to be handled. I think I will program it. I have not come across any module which does that